# BigCommerce and shopify API

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, shopify, bigcommerce

I am trying to build a mobile app for a Big Commerce based shop and Shopify Based app. We want to implement a  User Login Feature

There don't seem to be any straight forward Big Commerce API and Shopify to achieve this.  Can some body throw some light on how to implement a simple Login API's and cart API's.

Comment: Are you trying to create a mobile login for the merchant that owns the store or a customer of the merchant's store?

Comment: For Customers of merchant that will able to login through there account in mobile app...

Comment: Hi Alyss ... I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this if you were just creating a wrapper for the browser experience, however, there's no tokenization for customer login. As a result, you either have to hijack the entire account creation process through the storefront so you have control of a password assigned to customer accounts or forgo the account login process as the passwords aren't exposed/can't be validated against.

Comment: @HimanDhawan You can on shopify plus using the multipass resource: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/multipass